# Managing references of .Net executable file by PowerShell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, .net-4.6

Is there possibility to change path to dlls folder in already existed exe file by powershell script?

I'm using .Net Framework 4.6+ and looking for the way to store ddls separately and set path to dlls folder after installation dynamically.

Comment: The question is very unclear. It needs a example and more specific information

Comment: Net library wants all dlls in same folder as Net executable.  Net will automatically copy the dlls to folder.  You should add any dlls to c# project by using option ADD EXISTING ITEM.  Then browse to the PowerShell Folder and select the dll.

Comment: My goal to put exe file separately from dlls after build. Folders with dll and exe could be anywhere. One of existed solution is to put dll to GAC. But I'm looking for any additional one.

Comment: Reference information saved in an assembly does not contain the file path. CLR relies on a few resolution steps to locate such references at runtime. Therefore, there is nothing to change and you asked an invalid question.